# Strange viewport shading issue with perspective camera

Tags: 3d-view, shaders

I have been having this very strange problem when viewing geometry through a perspective camera in the viewport. It doesn't matter what kind of shading I apply and it doesn't happen with the orthographic camera or when I just navigate around normally. The geometry looks almost transparent and the edges have this weird jagged quality.

I am using Blender 3.2 on Windows 10. Graphics card is Nvidia GTX 1060 Max Q design. Any idea what might be going on?

[image]

Comment: maybe tweak the Clip Start and Clip End values of your camera?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks yeah I think it was this Z-fighting caused by the camera clip. My camera was quite far away, my clipping range was unnecessarily wide, and I was zoomed in really close--from the normal camera distance it looked fine. 

I expect some of this comes from my old graphics card as I don't have this issue on my newer computer.